# Can we use AccountId20 with babe and other pallets?

Tags: staking, frontier, grandpa, babe

As frontier now integrate natively the AccountId20 type, I wonder if it is compatible with all other pallets like BABE, Staking, ... Is there a place where we can check it or do we know some compatibility issue ?
This will help solving the UX between substrate and EVM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it with most pallets we already did this.

And I suggest you ask for some more specific question.

A note here, BABE, GRANDPA and ImOnline use keystore on node side the session keys are still the session keys which doesn't affect your system account.

Comment: thank you for the reply, couldn't ask really specific question as it was really targeted to know if the overall substrate frame was supporting it. You implemented that with darwinia I guess ?